# get date difference in java, use of getDate()

Tags: java

I am co-working with a group, I want to ask how can i get the date difference from a formate of "Sat Feb 23 00:00:00 GMT 2013". The pickerfrom and to is a calendar, and getDate returns that formate. How can I get the date difference in days? any idea?

```
 /*   Current format  Sat Feb 23 00:00:00 GMT 2013  */
 Date date_from = pickerFrom.getDate();
 Date date_to = pickerTo.getDate();

 int date_diff = (int)((date_to)-(date_from));
```

Comment: Date is not an integer!

Comment: You need to tell us more. In what format do you want the difference? Do you want difference in `days`, `months`?

Comment: I want the date different in days

Answer (score 4):

Checkout [getting the difference between date in days in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796841/getting-the-difference-between-date-in-days-in-java)

My preference would be to use Joda time - it has many useful date functions that'll make your life much easier when it comes to dates and date manipulation

Answer (score 1):

You can get the difference in milliseconds of each date and subtract these values.

```
long diff = date_to.getTime() - date_from.getTime();
```

will return you the number of milliseconds between the two dates.

Then, you can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125311/how-to-convert-milliseconds-into-hours-and-days/12125375#12125375) to get the number of hours, days,... out of these milliseconds.