# multiple timer in table representing remaining time to expire, Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular7

I have a table with multiple rows. Need to display timer, which will indicate the remaining time in n Days, x Hrs, y Min and z Secs.

I'm able to calculate remaining time using

[REF Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125311/how-to-convert-milliseconds-into-hours-and-days).

and I'm calling same function in column using {{myXYZFunction()}}

its calculating date and time as expected

but I think function call is lagging,

many time seconds are getting updated after 2 seconds,  and it is not showing smooth transition for seconds like 1,2,3,4... 60
Its somewhat like 1,2,4,6,8,10,12,13,14,15,17... 60

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise you generally want to avoid having function calls directly in the as this is called every change detection cycle. [Performace tips](https://angular-guru.com/blog/angular-performance-tips)

A much better approach would to update a member variable to the values you wish to display. For example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: '
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Time left</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="time in times">
          <td>{{time.date}}</td>
          <td>{{time.counter | async}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  '
})
export class MyComponent {
  public times;

  constructor() {
    // Creates an observable that is triggers every second.
    // Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(_ => this.time = myXYZFunction());
  }

  setupTimes() {
    const rawTimes = this.getTimes(); 
    this.times = [];
    rawTimes.forEach(tm => this.times.push({date: tm, counter: this.setupCounter(tm)});
  }

  setupCounter(time) {
    return Observable.interval(1000).pipe(map(_ => myXYZFunction(time)));
  }

  /**
  * Collect all the dates that should be displayed from the backend or use a  static array.
  */
  getTimes(): number[]{
    return [];
  }
}
```

In this way you control that your function is only called when it needs to be called. Reducing unnecessary load and removing the UI lag you're observing.

**EDIT**

As noted that the counter and date will be displayed as a table the example has been adapted. Please note that we form a object out of the date and countdown timer. None the less what is trying to be achieved here is quite costly and likely will lag beyond a few dates. 
Additionally we take advantage of the async pipe to not have to worry about unsubscribing. Unless you truly must have to the second accuracy, I would increase the counter to once every few seconds or minutes if possible. This will greatly reduce the load on the browser.

```
setupCounter(time) { // Updated every minute.
  return Observable.interval(60000).pipe(map(_ => myXYZFunction(time)));
}
```

Comment: the problem is that its in ```*ngFor``` and it has different  input.

Comment: I'm not sure I  understand your issue, could you post the portion of your code?

Comment: <table> 
<row 1>
Col 1 is 21-Feb-19 and col 2 is 22 days 5:49:29 hours, where second column is timer(countdown) for col 1

I think it might help you